# How Can i share a post using the post id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using Koala gem and in my UI i have an share link. How can i share the posts using the post id. Can it be done like this.

```
@facebook = FacebookToken.first
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@facebook.access_token)
@graph.put_object(params[:post_id], "share",:message => "First!")
```

It gives the following error

```
 Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 240, message: (#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user. [HTTP 403]
```

I thing something going wrong with permission. I have added the following permission in the fave bool app

```
"share_item,manage_pages,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,create_event,read_insights, manage_notifications"
```

Do I need to some other permission to share a post using post id

Comment: do you need a method at Facebook-Graph-API or method in framework? and yes, you need to use `publishing` method, like `POST /profile_ID/feed`

Comment: @loldop So I can do that through put_object method.

Comment: i use `POST` instead. try to use `PUT`

Comment: I have updated the question please look into that..

Comment: Ok, i will see it later. now i find something interesting for you: [similar_question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069906/user-must-have-accepted-tos-facebook-graph-api-error-when-posting-photos-to-gr)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in **put_object** is not the post ID, but the ID of who is sharing it, be it a page or user.

So instead of saying:

```
@graph.put_object(params[:post_id] ...
```

You would say:

```
//the current user
@graph.put_object('me' ...

or

//any user that you have a UID for
@graph.put_object(@user.uid ...

or

//a page that you have post permissions for
@graph.put_object(@facebook_page.id ...
```

Also in a future version of Koala, put_object will be a bit different, and you should go ahead and switch over to [**put_connection**](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb#L122).